# Toggle Function For CSS3 Nav Bar

Tags: jquery, html

Looking to get jquery toggle function working for my nav bar. I want to be able to click on the "about" and "philanthropy" sections to open up the UL lists inside and also be able to close the upon click. The ul nested in each should only display when clicked.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/IL1agD5.png"/></a></div>
            <div class="chapter"><a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RPIvgdD.png"/></a></div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>

                <li class="dropdown"><a href="">About ▾</a>
                    <ul class = "sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">History</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brothers</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <li class = "dropdown"><a href="">Philanthropy ▾</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Kovacs Color Run</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Greek God</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Boys & Girls Club</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                <li><a href="#">Membership</a>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

            </ul>
        </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

#wrapper {
    min-width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

header {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    margin:0 auto;

}
.logo{
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.chapter {
    float:right;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-right:10px;
}


.menu{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 ;
    text-align:center;
    clear:both
}

ul.menu {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border-left:solid 1px #22674A;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.menu > li {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:16.66%;
    border-style:1px #22674A;
}
ul.menu li:first-child a {
    border-left:none;
}
ul.menu ul li a {
    border:none;
}
ul.menu ul {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    border-left:none;
    border:solid 1px #22674A;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;

}
ul.menu a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    color: #22674A;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:500;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    border-left:solid 1px #22674A; 
}
ul.menu li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown").click(function(){
    $(".sub-menu").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/mc38nkdm/

Comment: For one, you aren't including jQuery in the jsfiddle. Use `slideToggle()`. http://jsfiddle.net/6pe04r7u/

Comment: Just opened it and its there in the javascript section

Comment: Right, but you need to include the jQuery library at the top left of the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hide your submenus. Then, change your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub-menu").hide();
    $(".dropdown").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").toggle(1000);
        return false; 
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/mc38nkdm/1/

Comment: Hey Praveen sorry to bother you again but the code has a slight problem. When I try to click on the sub-menu items it also toggles up. I need it to only toggle when .dropdown is clicked and then the sub-menu items route to other parts of my website.

Comment: I don't understand. What happens?

Comment: When I click on the sub menu items rather then directing to the part of the website listed, it toggles back up. I need the menu to only toggle when the main menu button is pressed ie home, about, philanthropy

Comment: @LeonardLabita Remove the return false.

Comment: After removing the return false, the menu no longer toggles

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope your `toggle` to only the `.sub-menu` that is a child of the clicked element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".sub-menu").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/1hkj9fvh/) to see a working example using `find` and `toggle` function. U can also add in the CSS `display:none;` to sub-menu style, so the submenus do no appear at load.

Hope it useful!